# Why is this function returning a list when called within another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My function is set to return a dictionary. When called, it returns the dictionary. However, if I call the function from within another function, it returns a list.

`

```
  def draw(self, num: int) -> dict:
    drawn_dict = {}
    if num > len(self.contents):
      return self.contents
    else:
      while num >= 1:
        drawn_num = self.contents.pop(random.randint(0, len(self.contents) - 1))
        drawn_dict.setdefault(drawn_num, 0)
        drawn_dict[drawn_num] +=1
        num -= 1
      return drawn_dict


def experiment(hat, expected_balls, num_balls_drawn, num_experiments):
  matches = 0
  full_match = 0
  count = 0
  print(hat.draw(num_balls_drawn))


print(hat.draw(5))
```

`

When I call the draw function and print the result, I get the dictionary as expected. But when the draw function is called and result is printed within the experiment function, I get a list.

Comment: Look at the if condition in `draw`. I guess `self.contents` is the list you see.

Answer (score 0):

What is a type of the `self.contents`? I thing it is the `list` and this is answer to your question :-)

```python
  def draw(self, num: int) -> dict:
    drawn_dict = {}
    if num > len(self.contents):
      return self.contents  # <- THIS
    else:
      while num >= 1:
        drawn_num = self.contents.pop(random.randint(0, len(self.contents) - 1))
        drawn_dict.setdefault(drawn_num, 0)
        drawn_dict[drawn_num] +=1
        num -= 1
      return drawn_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized the issue. I was calling the draw function before experiment function, and by calling draw, I was editing the self.contents list which affected its length thereby triggering the "if num> len(self.contents)". So function works as expected when I don't modify the list before actually using it!